# Should I quit my job because I lack experience?

Tags: career-development, professionalism, productivity, resignation

I'm just 18 years old, so I don't have a lot of experience. I currently work for a company that develops online games for a local casino. My job is to create servers that will support Flash clients. This is not very complicated, but it's not easy, either. Because I lack experience, I sometimes need to use Google to look things up (I can be proud that I've never copied code written by others).

Some of my friends and even my parents say that I'm a swindler, that I do what I don't know, and that it'd be better if I quit. I understand this, but on the other hand I feel comfortable in this company. I always finish my work on time and I've never had more than little bugs in my applications.

I am really confused about what I should do. Quit now and finish university at first or keep learning from projects (with reading books of course)?

Comment: A little secret. To some extent everyone is faking it in their jobs, even the experts.

Comment: I think it is time to find frinds that don't belittle you.

Comment: Related: [Importance of learning to google efficiently for a programmer?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/65918/25936), [Google is good or bad for programmer?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25063/google-is-good-or-bad-for-programmer)

Comment: I would say that finishing university is orthogonal to if your doing your job right. I believe that there is more danger in what you are *not* checking rather then what you are. Say - there is nothing wrong in searching how to store passwords, if md5 is secure or what is salt. However the danger might be in not searching for them because you don't know to not store them in plaintext. I don't know what you are looking up and why so I cannot answer if your knowledge is sufficient. University can provide you with knowledge of what you don't know.

Comment: Welcome to the IT industry.  Seriously, i actually put down (or at least mention during interviews) that I am really good at using google.  it's not my main skill, obviously, but it shows i'm more than willing to learn new things on my own, and that I can find solutions to problems.

Comment: Do what everyone does: fake it until you make it.  Seriously, if you can make anything work, you are already better than many who have been in the field for years.  And  **stop hanging around all those negative people.**  I expect they are just jealous because they can't keep up with you.

Comment: If in 18 months you still have these same problems, its time to find a new job, because it would mean you don't have the ability to learn Flash. Of course in 18 months it won't matter because that won't be the case.  Learning only from a book is sort of useless, a book won't get into the many thousands ways a project can go wrong, otherwise the auhor would never finish said book.

Comment: I'm a much more experienced developer than you and I spend 2/3 of my life Googling things, scouring StackOverflow or with my head buried in the Java/.NET documentation. As @johnfx said, the older you get the more you realise that everyone is making it up as they go along: all experience does is allow you to make it up more accurately as you go along.

Comment: @Jon Story - Also you gain valuable skills of knowing HOW to look things up efficiently. When you are just starting out you often don't even know the terms to Google. A veteran programmer might think "I need the observer pattern here...now how do I implement that again?"

Comment: @JohnFx: Peyton Manning is not faking it. Just ask his wife.

Comment: if everyone quit because they don't have experience, no one would ever get experience.... just saying

Comment: If you were hired, and now you get paid for what you do, that's proof that yo **do not** lack experience.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This job sounds like a great way to *get* the experience you lack. Using Google (or Stack Overflow!) to read up on how to do things properly is not a problem, it's a perfectly reasonable **solution**. Nobody knows everything, and knowing *how to figure out* how to solve a problem is *at least as important* as just knowing how to solve the problem.

It sounds like you are performing your job competently. If your boss has no real problems with your work, continue working. You'll gain valuable experience in an actual work environment, and build your technical skills while you do.

Additionally, being able to face a problem you don't already know how to solve is a positive trait. The resourcefulness to research and implenent a solution is a valuable skill.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. You've really helped me a lot.

Comment: +1 I agree with all points. To help you even further, just remember that StackOverflow exists because *people need to look things up all the time*, and do -- no matter how long they've been doing their job.  Unless I'm missing something to the story, I wouldn't listen to  your friends or parents about this matter *at all*.  Keep working if your boss is happy and you are happy.

Comment: I'd like to add, that you should be copying as much code as possible if the License on the code allows it. No reason to reinvent things.

Comment: +1 for "it sounds like you are performing your job competently". If you weren't then you would probably know already. How do your friends and family know what your employer expects? Also, I suspect you are being paid a pittance compared to what a truly skilled developer would be getting paid to do the same job, so the company probably looks at you as a bargain.

Comment: @jcmeloni Unless you're Jon Skeet.....

Answer (score 12):

Let me ask you a question, **are you learning and enjoy performing your tasks**? If that answer is yes, then stay. If not, then move on to something better. Life is too short.

There are many jobs out there where it is difficult to have all the knowledge to complete it properly. There is always something to learn, innovate and execute. If it ever gets to a point where this is not possible, we might as well start living in the trees as monkeys.

Comment: I simply love this work. I've strongly decided to stay and I don't have doubts anymore thanks to you and @Jim.

Answer (score 12):

Whether you should quit (or cut back) your job in order to go to school is a seperate issue from whether you are being fraudulent in accepting the pay for your current job.

IT is a funny business at least from the outside, people will suggest that you are basically doing nothing, sitting on your butt all day, so no stress and no being tired from working, or they'll ask why don't you make a new game or website that makes millions, why don't you whip up a new E-Bay over the weekend for the church fundraiser....

Unless they are or have done your job, they almost certainly have no idea of the skills necessary in order to do it, and unless they need those skills, they also have no idea as to the worth of those skills.

A job is fundamentally no different than buying a nicknack at a flea market -- the exchange is what determines the value, the seller may have bought it for more or less than he is willing to take, and the buyer probably wants to pay less but may be willing to pay more.  So...

As long as your employer is happy with paying you, and you are happy with the pay you are being given, ignore the bystanders.  They aren't part of the deal and their opinions of Dogs Playing Poker don't matter.

Now, all that said -- you're only 18, so there's a good chance that your current job won't last you a life time.  What you should be considering is not whether you are getting paid more than your worth, but how you will continue getting paid the amount you are accustomed to.

Comment: +1 - _What you should be considering ... you are accustomed to._ Well said. I was all for him keeping the job, just like everyone else, until I read that he's 18 and might well end up not finishing college. In the short term, it doesn't seem like a big deal - in the long term, it is. Not that you necessarily learn so much in college, but **you need it** on your resume in many cases.

Comment: Sometimes people get a recommendation to find a new job. In your case, if your parents call you a swindler, it's time to find yourself a new set of parents. What you have been doing is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8):

Your job is to solve problems, "to create servers that will support Flash clients" just happens to be the problem you are currently facing.
And that's *exactly* what you are doing. Solving problems can be done in several ways, by experience but also by research ("to use Google to look things up").

Your ability to set up servers for Flash clients won't be what will make you good in your job. There will be always new problems you are going to face and it's impossible to know about everything beforehand. And being able to solve the problem non-the-less will be what makes you worth being employed.

So, no, don't quit. You are doing your job perfectly fine, there is no reason to quit.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this from personal experience. I walked into my first (and current) job having years of programming experience but never having used Ruby on Rails and very little of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. I also had never maintained (or now) built a real-world application before. However, I learned on-the-job what I needed to know (with liberal SO usage), asked questions when necessary, and I am doing very well. To second what others have said, a lack of experience means that you need to get some, and a job is a great way (if not the best) to do so.

**tl;dr** You advance your career by gaining experience, and no one knows everything; also, if you can do well with what you already know, you're doing something right.